# How to use textTheme in ElevatedButton?

Tags: flutter

I'm migrating from RaisedButton to ElevatedButton but there is something that I don't figure out how to do it, in my themeData I have:

```
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
              buttonColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
              textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
            )
```

textTheme is something that I like because it's use black or white color depends on the background color, it's a life saver. How can I do that on ElevatedButton? Doesn't have textTheme

Answer (score 0):

came across this yesterday, I think this should work for you.

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (states) => TextStyle(
        // add your styles here
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

that's how it works now

Comment: But in that way I need to specify each text color for each button, is correct? I'm looking for something that use it automatically just as RaisedButton textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary

For example, if I put background color white on both buttons, raisedbutton will use black text color itself, and ElevatedButton will get always white and I don't want specify the color myself